# subtracting double vector returns expanded notation

Tags: c++, vector

My c++ code is returning expanded notation when I try and subtract the top values.

```
    vector<std::string> smarkdat
    vector<std::string> markdat;
    vector<double> doubleMdat;
    vector<double> sdoubleMdat;
    markdat = getmarketbuyData();
    smarkdat = getmarketsellData();
    transform(smarkdat.begin(), smarkdat.end(), back_inserter(sdoubleMdat), [](string const& val) {return stod(val);});
    auto sbiggestMark = std::max_element(std::begin(sdoubleMdat), std::end(sdoubleMdat));
    transform(markdat.begin(), markdat.end(), back_inserter(doubleMdat), [](string const& val) {return stod(val);});
    auto biggestMark = std::max_element(std::begin(doubleMdat), std::end(doubleMdat));
    std::cout << "The highest seller is " << *sbiggestMark << " at position " << std::distance(std::begin(sdoubleMdat), sbiggestMark) << std::endl;
    std::vector<double> difference(sdoubleMdat.size(), 0.0);

    for ( std::vector<double>::size_type i = 0; i < sdoubleMdat.size(); i++ )
        {
             difference[i] = std::abs( sbiggestMark[i] - biggestMark[i] );
             cout << difference[i] << endl;
        }
```

output:

```
8.636e-05
```

the vector data is string `0.000000200` converted into double.

How do I return a regular subtracted value of 2 doubles and not the very obvious incorrect return value?

Comment: i think you can try biginteger or store the difference in unsigned long long

Comment: `std::fixed` and `std::setprecision` are your friends.

Comment: @remyabel can you provide more details?

Comment: `the vector data is string 0.000000200 converted into double`  If you're talking about `difference` the value is not from a string.  It is the value when two `double` values have been subtracted.

Comment: @mine I still don't understand what the problem is.  You have two vectors with double values,  You get the absolute value of the difference of each value and store in the vector, thus yielding a vector of doubles.  So what is the problem?  If it's the way you want the value displayed *on the screen*, then you *format* the data the way you want to see it on the screen by using the i/o manipulators.  If it's some other problem, then you need to clarify your question.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie 8.636e-05 is garbage

Comment: @mine - `8.636e-05 is garbage`  It is the result of a subtraction of two doubles, so it's your data that is causing the "garbage".   In any event, that number is `0.00008636`  Is that garbage?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie not in that format.  error: 'setprecision' is not a member of 'std' even with <cstring> and <limits> set in my main.cpp. No path I choose will return that value in human readable format.

Comment: @mine - You didn't `#include <iomanip>`

Comment: Thank you!  Post it as an answer so I can click the button! Precision fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the issue is that you want to set the output without the scientific notation,  then use `std::setprecision` and `std::fixed` found in `<iomanip>`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double x = fabs(sqrt(2.0) - sqrt(2.0001));
    cout << x << "\n"; 
    cout << setprecision(10) << fixed << x << '\n';
}
```

Live example: http://ideone.com/B3IfDF

Comment: @kuroi neko printf borks in the exact same manner, still requiring precision. It doesn't like those long doubles either. Precision is truly the correct answer.

Comment: It all depends on what your definitions of "regular" and "very obvious incorrect" are...